# What is wrong in my code for calculation?

Tags: javascript, php

```
<body onload='hideTotal()'>
    <div id="wrap">
        <form action="" id="cakeform" onsubmit="return false;">
        <div>
            <div class="cont_order">
               <fieldset>
                <legend>Make your cake!</legend>
                <label >Size Of the Cake</label>
                <label class='radiolabel'><input type="radio"  name="selectedcake" value="Round6" onclick="calculateTotal()" />Round cake 6" -  serves 8 people ($20)</label><br/>
                <label class='radiolabel'><input type="radio"  name="selectedcake" value="Round8" onclick="calculateTotal()" />Round cake 8" - serves 12 people ($25)</label><br/>
                <label class='radiolabel'><input type="radio"  name="selectedcake" value="Round10" onclick="calculateTotal()" />Round cake 10" - serves 16 people($35)</label><br/>

                <br/>
                <label >Quantity</label>

                <select id="filling" name='filling' onchange="calculateTotal()">
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
                <option value="4">4</option>
                <option value="5">5</option>
                <option value="6">6</option>
                <option value="7">7</option>
                <option value="8">8</option>
                <option value="9">9</option>
                <option value="10">10</option>
               </select>
                <br/>

                <div id="totalPrice"></div>

                </fieldset>
            </div>

            <div class="cont_details">
                <fieldset>
                <legend>Contact Details</legend>
                <label for='name'>Name</label>
                <input type="text" id="name" name='name' />
                <br/>
                <label for='address'>Address</label>
                <input type="text" id="address" name='address' />
                <br/>
                <label for='phonenumber'>Phone Number</label>
                <input type="text"  id="phonenumber" name='phonenumber'/>
                <br/>
                </fieldset>
            </div>
            <input type='submit' id='submit' value='Submit' onclick="calculateTotal()" />
        </div>  
       </form>
    </div>
```

And this is Javascript

```
 var cake_prices = new Array();
 cake_prices["Round6"]=20;
 cake_prices["Round8"]=25;
 cake_prices["Round10"]=35;


 var filling_prices= new Array();
 filling_prices["1"]=1;
 filling_prices["2"]=2;
 filling_prices["3"]=3;
 filling_prices["4"]=4;
 filling_prices["5"]=5;
 filling_prices["6"]=6;
 filling_prices["7"]=7;
 filling_prices["8"]=8;
 filling_prices["9"]=9;
 filling_prices["10"]=10;


function getCakeSizePrice()
{  
    var cakeSizePrice=0;

    var theForm = document.forms["cakeform"];

    var selectedCake = theForm.elements["selectedcake"];

    for(var i = 0; i < selectedCake.length; i++)
    {

        if(selectedCake[i].checked)
        {

            cakeSizePrice = cake_prices[selectedCake[i].value];

            break;
        }
    }
    //We return the cakeSizePrice
    return cakeSizePrice;
}

function calculateTotal()
{

    var cakePrice = getCakeSizePrice() + getFillingPrice() + candlesPrice() + insciptionPrice();

    var divobj = document.getElementById('totalPrice');
    divobj.style.display='block';
    divobj.innerHTML = "Total Price For the Cake $"+cakePrice;

}

function hideTotal()
{
    var divobj = document.getElementById('totalPrice');
    divobj.style.display='none';
}
```

I am trying to calculating total value. frankly, I just assemble this code from multiples sources. Still am not receiving total value. Due to less coding knowledge, I am unable to understand the error ?

Comment: Arrays in javascript are numerically indexed

Comment: Where those functions are defined  `getFillingPrice() + candlesPrice() + insciptionPrice();` ?

Comment: Do arrays in Javascript actually exist. You can use the same syntax for associative arrays. Just a thought

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you don't have the following functions defined: `getFillingPrice()` + `candlesPrice()` + `insciptionPrice()`

If you don't need them, you can change this:

```
var cakePrice = getCakeSizePrice() + getFillingPrice() + candlesPrice() + insciptionPrice();
```

into this:

```
var cakePrice = getCakeSizePrice() * document.getElementById('filling').value;
```

and it will start working.

I also suggest choosing a different ID name for the quantity, so that it would make more sense the next time you look at your code. Change this:

```
<select id="filling" name='filling' onchange="calculateTotal()">
```

into something like this:

```
<select id="qty" name='qty' onchange="calculateTotal()">
```

and revise the javascript code as well:

```
var cakePrice = getCakeSizePrice() * document.getElementById('qty').value;
```

---

### **UPDATE**

**Q: "How can i send this form data, after submission, to my mail id?"**

Actually, there is more than one way to do that, but they all require **a server-side script page for sending the mail**. On a PHP server, for example, you may use [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) or similar classes to do the job. In any case, however, you will need to collect the data and send it to that script page.

There are also several ways for collecting and sending the data to the script page which sends the mail. Some commonly used methods are as follows:

1. You can use **javascript to validate** the form and then do a **redirect to the server-side script** page passing the **data as GET variable**s. *(least favourite in this list, not recommended at all)*
2. You can use **javascript to validate** the form and if valid **trigger form submission through HTML** which can **POST data to server-side script** page for mailing. *(again not recommended, better not trust javascript on validation)*
3. You can **send the form via simple HTML POST** (or GET, but not recommended) to another page where the **data will be validated and mailed/redirected for error handling by the server-side script**. *(HTML setup explained below, server-side is a whole different story)*
4. You can use **javascript to collect the data and send it with an AJAX request** to a **server-side script which validates the data, sends the e-mail if valid or returns errors if not** *(nice one, a little trickier though, but cool)*

Method #4 may prove to be a little advanced, so let me explain method #3:

**HTML:**

```
<body onload='hideTotal()'>
  <div id="wrap">
    <form id="cakeform" 
          method="post" 
          action="<!-- Link to server-side script page here -->">
      <div>
        <div class="cont_order">
          <fieldset>
            <legend>Make your cake!</legend>
            <span>Size Of the Cake</span>
            <br/>
            <input type="radio" 
                   id="r6" 
                   name="selectedcake" 
                   value="Round6" 
                   onclick="calculateTotal()" />
            <label for="r6" 
                   class='radiolabel'>Round cake 6" -  serves 8 people ($20)</label>
            <br/>
            <input type="radio" 
                   id="r8" 
                   name="selectedcake" 
                   value="Round8" 
                   onclick="calculateTotal()" />
            <label for="r8" 
                   class='radiolabel'>Round cake 8" - serves 12 people ($25)</label>
            <br/>
            <input type="radio" 
                   name="selectedcake" 
                   id="r10" 
                   value="Round10" 
                   onclick="calculateTotal()" />
            <label for="r10" 
                   class='radiolabel'>Round cake 10" - serves 16 people($35)</label>
            <br/>
            <br/>
            <label for="qty">Quantity</label>
            <select id="qty" name='qty' onchange="calculateTotal()">
              <option value="1">1</option>
              <option value="2">2</option>
              <option value="3">3</option>
              <option value="4">4</option>
              <option value="5">5</option>
              <option value="6">6</option>
              <option value="7">7</option>
              <option value="8">8</option>
              <option value="9">9</option>
              <option value="10">10</option>
            </select>
            <br/>
            <div id="totalPrice"></div>
            <input type="hidden" name="total" id="total" />
          </fieldset>
        </div>
        <div class="cont_details">
          <fieldset>
            <legend>Contact Details</legend>
            <label for="name">Name</label>
            <input type="text" id="name" name="name" />
            <br/>
            <label for="address">Address</label>
            <input type="text" id="address" name="address" />
            <br/>
            <label for="phonenumber">Phone Number</label>
            <input type="text" id="phonenumber" name="phonenumber" />
            <br/>
            </fieldset>
        </div>
        <input type='submit' id='submit' value='Submit' />
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</body>
```

**Javascript Function to Change:**

```
function calculateTotal() {
  var cakePrice = getCakeSizePrice() * document.getElementById('qty').value;
  var divobj = document.getElementById('totalPrice'),
      hiddenInput = document.getElementById('total');
  divobj.style.display='block';
  divobj.innerHTML = "Total Price For the Cake $"+cakePrice;
  hiddenInput.value = cakePrice;
}
```

Briefly, we assigned `POST` as the method for the `<form>` element, placed an `<input>` element with a `type="hidden"` attribute, removed the useless function from the submit `<button>`, and revized the `calculateTotal()` function so that the total price will be stored in the hidden input element.

Here is a CodePen link where you can see the whole code: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Vebomx

Comment: Awesome Bro. i Love the way you describe :), How can i send this form data, after submission, to my mail id.

Answer (score -1):

There are functions missing in your script to multiply the cake price with selected quantity, candles price and inscription price.  I have assumed candles and inscription prices to be 5 each and am multiplying the same with quantity too. You can change that or make an array just like filling (quantity).

```
                        var cake_prices = new Array();
                    cake_prices["Round6"]=20;
                    cake_prices["Round8"]=25;
                    cake_prices["Round10"]=35;


                    var filling_prices= new Array();
                    filling_prices["1"]=1;
                    filling_prices["2"]=2;
                    filling_prices["3"]=3;
                    filling_prices["4"]=4;
                    filling_prices["5"]=5;
                    filling_prices["6"]=6;
                    filling_prices["7"]=7;
                    filling_prices["8"]=8;
                    filling_prices["9"]=9;
                    filling_prices["10"]=10;

                    // candles price
                    var candles_price = 5;

                    //inscription price 
                    var inscription_price = 5;

                   function getCakeSizePrice()
                   {  
                       var cakeSizePrice=0;

                       var theForm = document.forms["cakeform"];

                       var selectedCake = theForm.elements["selectedcake"];

                       for(var i = 0; i < selectedCake.length; i++)
                       {

                           if(selectedCake[i].checked)
                           {

                               cakeSizePrice = cake_prices[selectedCake[i].value];

                               break;
                           }
                       }
                       //We return the cakeSizePrice
                       return cakeSizePrice;
                   }

                   function calculateTotal()
                   {

                       var theForm = document.forms["cakeform"];
                       var cakePrice = getCakeSizePrice();

                       cakePrice = cakePrice * filling_prices[theForm.elements['filling'].value];

                       //need to add candles and inscription price
                       var candlesPrice = candles_price * theForm.elements['filling'].value;
                       var inscriptionPrice = inscription_price * theForm.elements['filling'].value;

                       cakePrice += candlesPrice + inscriptionPrice;

                       var divobj = document.getElementById('totalPrice');
                       divobj.style.display='block';
                       divobj.innerHTML = "Total Price For the Cake $"+cakePrice;

                   }

                   function hideTotal()
                   {
                       var divobj = document.getElementById('totalPrice');
                       divobj.style.display='none';
                   }
```